# Need to 'gatsby clean' with essentially every code change

Tags: graphql, gatsby, react-ssr

So, our team are working on a Gatsby website, and it's working correctly for most of us.
One developer, however, needs to run `gatsby clean` on essentially every single code change.

Doesn't matter if it's an error, changing a text value or adding markup.

I realise this is a fairly vague question, but I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Does the dev see the output in the terminal `success Re-building development bundle` when running `gatsby develop` and changing some code? Also, just in case I would check setting a different browser.

Comment: Have you checked your node, yarn, etc. versions?

Comment: Ah. I finally found it. Some components had incorrect casing in their imports. Weird it works the first time after `gatsby clean` though!

Comment: @MitchEff can you please share examples of what you discovered and fixed it for you.